# Kivy on debian 7

Tags: python, kivy

How to install Kivy in Debian 7?
I tried installing it using "apt-get", as a debian package, using pip. None of these methods work.
It throws dependency error "libc6 version 2.14 or above required". I have 2.13 in my system, which I tried to upgrade to 2.14, but that does not work either.

Comment: I have a hard time keeping track of Debian versions. Is 7 the current stable version?

Comment: Yes it's known as Wheezy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel stupid answering my own question, but if anyone ever faces the same problem... they should get the answer here.

The ppa on the kivy site didn't work for me, there were dependency issues with libc6.
I added this ppa to my /etc/apt/sources.list file - deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian sid main
Which resolved the issue.

Comment: This solution is a little problematic because it consists in adding the repository of Debian 8. Although it did worked for me, I think this means I am no longer using Debian 7, as the question wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried following the instructions on the [kivy website](http://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-linux.html#debian)? There is apparently a ppa at `deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/kivy-team/kivy/ubuntu oneiric main`, or `deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/kivy-team/kivy-daily/ubuntu oneiric main` for daily builds.

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't work. I refresh my package list and there's no change.

Comment: I suggest asking on the kivy mailing list or irc channel, maybe someone there will know the current status of the ppa.

Answer (score 0):

works with Kivy 1.8. Install Cython 0.20:

**step1**

pip install -I cython==0.20

**step2**

wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/K/Kivy/Kivy-1.8.0.tar.gz

**step3**

tar xvfz Kivy-1.8.0.tar.gz && cd ./Kivy-1.8.0

**step4**

python setup.py build_ext --inplace -f

**step5**

python setup.py install